# selenium only run the first test properly under a test class while launching with FireFox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to share a single *Chrome/Firefox* instance between the methods by using the `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` methods and using the `@classmethod` decorator. It works fine with Chrome but **failure in Firefox**. Here is the environment:

- Win10 x64,
- Python 3.7.2,
- Pycharm 18.3,
- Selenium 3.141.59,
- FireFox 64.0,
- geckodriver v0.23.0,
- Chrome V71.0.3578.98 64-bit,
- ChromeDriver 2.45

The expected results for the 2 test methods are 3 and 1.Test runs with Chrome matches the expectation, but doesn't work for Firefox.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True

class SearchTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # create a new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, executable_path="my\geckodriver\path")
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        # create a new Chrome session
        # cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome("my\chromedriver\path")
        # cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        # cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        cls.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")

    def test_search_by_category(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        self.search_field.send_keys("phone")
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names displayed
        # currently on result page using find_elements_by_xpath method
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']")
        self.assertEqual(3, len(products))

    def test_search_by_name(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        self.search_field.send_keys("salt shaker")
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names displayed
        # currently on result page using find_elements_by_xpath method
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']")
        self.assertEqual(1, len(products))

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

The expectation is like this (finished with Chrome):

```
test_search_by_category (main.SearchTests) ... ok 
test_search_by_name (main.SearchTests) ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 14.172s
OK
```

But with firefox, it always shows:

```
test_search_by_category (main.SearchTests) ... ok
test_search_by_name (main.SearchTests) ... FAIL
FAIL: test_search_by_name (main.SearchTests)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "G:\Thunder\PycharmProject\setests\searchtests.py", line 54, in test_search_by_name 
      self.assertEqual(1, len(products)) 
AssertionError: 1 != 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 13.568s
FAILED (failures=1)
```

I guess because the selenium run under firefox could not launch the 2nd test method and thus, it uses the previous `len(products)` value to compare with the expectation "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the firefox driver doesn't wait for the page to reload before it checks the number of the elements.  Check this issue

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4570

One possible solution is to navigate to your main page before each test runs.
To do this, you could add a `setup` method in your test and move the get page code as well as the reset input box code into this `setup` method.  Here is how it would look like:

```
def setUp(self):
    # navigate to the application home page
    self.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")
    # get the search textbox
    self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    self.search_field.clear()
```

Otherwise you need to write code to make sure the page is reloaded.